# PHP Docusign API - Line breaks in custom tabs disappear when second signature request is received

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to make an address Custom Tab with PHP as part of my envelope definition, and it works fine for the first signer. Line breaks are added as the initial registrant enters them. However when it reaches the second signer, the line breaks are removed from the document and address appears on one line.
How do I keep the line breaks for each signer (I have up to 5 signatures per document).

This is the text_tab creation snippet:

```
    $purchaserAddress = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Note([
        'anchor_string' => '/purchaser_address/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '-3', 'anchor_x_offset' => '-4',
        'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "1",
        'font' => "TimesNewRoman", 'font_size' => "size8", 'bold' => 'true', 'tab_label' => "Purchaser Address",
        'value' => $args['address'],
        'locked' => 'true', 'tab_id' => 'address'
    ]);
    $text_tabs[] = $purchaserAddress;
```

I've tried both Note and Text classes, and neither seem to remember the line breaks for subsequent signers. Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you add line breaks?

Comment: The user types their address into a <textarera></textarea> field on a registration form (HTML/PHP).

Comment: If you do the same thing not using an API, but using the web app - does it then work ok?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've never used Docusign's web app to set up envelopes. I'll have someone test it for me. I believe this may be a glitch on Docusign, I'll submit a support request with them too.

Comment: you can, perhaps, work around this by setting the height and width of the text area?

Comment: Thanks. Setting the height / width of the textarea doesn't do anything but setting it for the custom tab definition did.

Answer (score 1):

So I thought it might have to do with the way Docusign interprets "\n" but now I believe its how the Text / Note objects are defined. If you include the width / height properties, it treats the objects multi-lined for all signers (not just the first). In my opinion this is a glitch but at least it's not a difficult work around:

```
    $purchaserAddress = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text([
        'anchor_string' => '/purchaser_address/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '-3', 'anchor_x_offset' => '-4',
        'document_id' => "1", 'page_number' => "1",
        'font' => "TimesNewRoman", 'font_size' => "size8", 'bold' => 'true', 'tab_label' => "Purchaser Address",
        'value' => $args['address'],

        'height'=>'110', 'width'=>'400',

        'locked' => 'true', 'tab_id' => 'address'
    ]);
    $text_tabs[] = $purchaserAddress;
```

Comment: Thanks, we an improve documentation to explain this.